# Why can't I upload the file to the folder I need?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use carbon fields to create my own fields, which I use on the add new entry page of Word press. I need to select a file in the custom field, which will then be uploaded to the folder I need when I click publish entry. But for some reason this does not happen, the file does not appear in my folder, although other fields work as they should, what could be the reason? I'm checking in the open server now.

```
add_action('save_post', 'crb_save_post', 10, 3);

function crb_save_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if (!$update && defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    $file_info = $_FILES['crb_game_files'];

    if ($file_info['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $games_folder = get_template_directory() . '/games/';
        $post_folder = $games_folder . $post_id;

        if (file_exists($post_folder)) {
            $target_path = $post_folder . '/' . basename($file_info['name']);
            move_uploaded_file($file_info['tmp_name'], $target_path);
        }
    }
}









add_action('wp_after_insert_post', 'crb_after_insert_post', 10, 3);

function crb_after_insert_post($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if ($post->post_type === 'post') {
        $games_folder = get_template_directory() . '/games/';
        $post_folder = $games_folder . $post_id;

        if (!file_exists($post_folder)) {
            mkdir($post_folder);

        }
    }
}




 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'crb_load');
 function crb_load() {
    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
    \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
 }
```

Comment: If your in a child-theme, use `get_stylesheet_directory()` insted - else it will look in the parent themes files

Comment: @Stender I don't have a child theme. I have created 1 of my own and am developing it. I did not understand where to look for my files then, which I am trying to upload to the folder I need. I can't figure out what the error is, I kind of correctly select the folder to save, but the file doesn't appear there